# Unable to Perform Update Operation a Nested Item in Firebase Database?

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

> Hello Everyone, I am trying to perform a Update Operation in a Nested Firebase Database .
> This is the structure of the database:

[image]

> I am trying to Update the `title` text which has `Deviled Eggs` to `Deviled Eggs Updated` . I am showing the Data in a `RecyclerView`

> The Only thing I have right Now is the name **Appetizers and Snacks** .

> So basically , First I have to Locate the name **Appetizers and Snacks**  , then Move to the Top Node (`0` in this case). Then come down to `recipes` Node , then get the Current Adapter Key and finally Update the Data

> here is the `Adapter code` that i have tried till now:

```
 update.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {

                    Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
                    map.put("title", title.getText().toString());
                    map.put("time", timeReqd.getText().toString());
                    map.put("servings", servings.getText().toString());
                    map.put("ingredients", ingredients.getText().toString());
                    map.put("steps", steps.getText().toString());
                    map.put("image", image.getText().toString());


                    String received_data = holder.title.getText().toString();
                    //received data has value Appetizers and Snacks

                    FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference()
                            .child("All Categories")
                            .child(received_data)
                            
                            .updateChildren(map)
                            .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {

                                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                        dialog.dismiss();
                                    } else {
                                        Toast.makeText(context, "Failed to Update !", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                                    }

                                }
                            });
```

> I also wrote this Query :

```
Query query = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("All Categories").orderByChild("name").equalTo(received_data);
```

> I know the basics of Update operation but really cant figure out, what should i write here. Please provide Guidance. Thanks

Comment: is recipies child autogenerated(MRE0...)?

Comment: Yes , its autogenerated

Comment: @Sainita you  said can be hard coded above.

Comment: @Sainita you have to find that node on what basis you created it?

Comment: i received it as a json file.

Comment: @Sainita Have you solved the issue?

Comment: No, still trying to figure out !